# Setting dynamic urls for django filter

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

Context : I have little experience with Django and it's dynamic urls. In this project, I'm using `djangorestframework` and `django-filters` packages.
My models use `models.CharField` (owners, item, category...). Using filterset, I want to set a dynamic url.

Using the URL
`path('item**/categories=categoryname**', items-view.as_view(), name='category')` I need to specify the category name in the browser search box before I get the items in a named category. That's the way I'm testing it on the browser and by using the category name, I get all the items in that category being returned. I want to use the url in a react application.

Will it be a good practice to fetch that API as it is since I'm equating the category to the name of the category to obtain the list of items in that particular category? Or is there a way to set the url dynamically?

For instance, when using lookup_field for the product `id` I can set the url dynamically using `path('item/**<int:id>**', items-view.as_view(), name='category')` without hard coding the id in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't querystrings solve your problem?
If you are using drf plese check [drf filters](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/)
if you need to override the quertset method you can do that too
in your api view add something like

```
   def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)
        if 'category' in self.request.GET:
            return queryset.filter(category_name=self.request.GET['category'])
    return queryset
```